# Switching a base image with a thumbnail - Magento

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, thumbnails

I'm trying to switch a base image with a thumbnail when clicked (under product pages). For some reason I can't get it to work at all. Here's my code that creates the thumbnails:

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
    <div class="desktop more-views">
        <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
                <?php if ($this->isGalleryImageVisible($_image)): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" data-image-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>"
                                 width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's my JS code (in the file MY_THEME/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js) for switching the actual image:

```
wireThumbnails: function() {
        //trigger image change event on thumbnail click
        $j('.product-image-thumbs .thumb-link').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var jlink = $j(this);
            var target = $j('#image-' + jlink.data('image-index'));

            ProductMediaManager.swapImage(target);
        });
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've followed the solutions at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170795/switching-a-base-image-with-a-thumbnail-in-magento) link but they don't work! I wanted to comment on that post but I don't have enough reputation to do so! :( any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**: Here are the errors showing up on the console:

[image]

Each time I click on a thumbnail the last-most error comes up again and again...

Comment: Are you intentionally using '$j' opposed to just '$' for jquery - cause if so you'd need to add: var $j = $.noConflict(); to give it proper the proper reference

Comment: Ah right ok I see... where would I add this to the code? Sorry I'm new to this :/

Comment: You'd want to call it after jquery has loaded in, or at the very least, where you have the comment '//trigger image change event on thumbnail click' ... however, I'm wondering, what errors does the console show you when you try and run your code?

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for your help. I've added that bit of code and still not working unfortunately. The console is showing a few errors. I've edited my post to show these errors. Hope this helps to see what may be going wrong?

Comment: looks like you've got a few issues..but it looks like you're main issue is not having the JQuery library included.  Without knowing much more, or seeing the whole code base, what I'd recommend is including the JQuery CDN <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" ></script>  at the top of your html.  Then re-run, does that take care of the majority of the errors in the console?  Actually - looking at the 1st error "missing ) after ..." which means the jquery your including has some bad character or some other issue with it.  Replace where you reference jquery.min.js with the cdn

Comment: @Kyle Thank you Kyle. I've managed to get rid of a load of errors! My ```.min.js``` file was corrupted! I therefore downloaded a new copy and most of the errors have disappeared! However, the thumbnail issue still doesn't work :( The last error ```$j is not defined``` in the console replicates each time I click on a thumbnail

Comment: perfect - almost there then, you have a couple of options.  You could find every instance of '$j' and replace it with '$' (that's what I'd recommend cause you probably didn't actually want it as $j in the first place) or you could just force it by adding: var $j = $; near the top of your code - that will let everyone know you mean '$' when you use '$j'

Comment: @Kyle Hmm this is strange... those errors don't appear on the live site - just on my local version! I haven't got any errors on the live site... do you know what else could be wrong with my thumbnail code?

Comment: @Kyle Sorry Kyle for being all over the shop! I'm new to Magento and web dev so still getting to grips with it all! :S I really do wonder why I can't switch the base image when selecting thumbnails....

Comment: @Kyle I would be so grateful if you have any other ideas Kyle? Really sorry for pestering you! :(

Comment: there's really not enough to go off of without guessing.  I'd recommend taking it step by step.  Forget the image switching for the moment, just get a click event to register, as in, simply make it alert "hello" when you click on something.  Once that is working have it log the actual element that was clicked to the console.  You should really be posting all the different stuff you have tried so far to make it work...

Comment: @Kyle I feel so stupid now! It seems that my ```app.js``` script doesn't get called! I put an alert in the script and it doesn't get called at all (when loading the page or when clicking the thumbnails!).

Comment: sometimes have to start simple, now that you've found that hopefully the rest falls into place :)

Comment: Oh waw I got it working! I followed the instructions (on the link in my post) and (eventually) found the correct JS file.... then I had to change any ```$j``` to ```$``` like you said! Thanks so much for your help and patience - problem solved!

Comment: awesome job, way to stick with it!